# Simple Winsock2 Client/Server code in C++

Tags: windows, winsock, msdn, tcp, winsock2

I am trying to create a simple client/server system using 2 PCs and c++ code written using winSock2. The code was mostly borrowed from [here](https://goo.gl/53Xchj).

When I run the two programs on the same laptop, and use 'localhost' as an argument to the client. However, the client fails to connect when I try to run it on different computers, using the public IP of the server computer. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a firewall problem. Try to disable the firewall for a moment and check your application. If it works, open the needed listening port in the firewall.

Alon.